# TFS 2013 adding tester to a project

Tags: testing

I would like to ask a little help to Team Foundation Server 2013. I have created a test plan with test cases and I would like to add a user to this plan as a tester but she does not display in the Assign list of Testing Center. Where can I add this user and what role to the TFS project, please?

I want this user to run an acceptance test the project in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the user to `Contributors` group. If you add to other custom groups you need to set the permission accordingly besed on your requirements.

**Manage Project** (gear icon)  --> **Security** --> **Contributors**  --> **Members** --> **Add** --> Add user or group --> Enter the user/group or click **Browse** to pick up the user/group and check the name --> **Save Changes**

Once the user is added, then you can assign the test cases to the user.

---

**UPDATE:**

The least possible is the **Readers** group.

Based on my test, you need to give the `Create test runs` permission for the users to run tests. So, you can add the users to **Readers** group, then navigate to the specific user and set  `Create test runs` to `Allow` for the user (By default the permission `Create test runs` for Readers group is disabled). Of course you can also create a new TFS group for client users and set same permissions as the **Readers** group, also enable the `Create test runs` permission for the new group.

The users in **Readers** group, they can only `read` and can not do other things. That's not the `Full access`. So don't worry about that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you fro your answer, but I would like a solution (if it is possible) where I would give the least possible permissions for the testers. They being able to run just the test cases (no create, edit, delete, manage roles), because they are from the busuiness side (acceptance test).

Comment: @SándorHatvani The least possible is the `Readers` group, or just give the  `View test runs` permission only, then try that.

Comment: Yes, but I have to add Full access permission to the tester on Control page because if he does not have this permission he does not see the Test menu item on Web test page. This Full access truble me, a simple tester gains too much possibilities to do bad things, doesn't he?

Comment: @SándorHatvani Nothing serious, If you add the users to **Readers** group,  they can only `read ` and can not do other things. That's not the `Full access`. So don't worry about that.  Based on my test, you need to  give the `Create test runs` permission to the users. So, you can add the users to **Readers** group, then navigate to the specific user and set  `Create test runs` to `Allow` for the user.